# magento using blog from aheadworks

Tags: php, mysql, magento

Has anybody installed the blog module from aheadworks in magento successfully?

I've installed and it appeared to be ok, but the posts don't show on the front end, it's just a blank screen!

Using magento 1.4.2 - be a really usefull tool for us, but can't get it to work.

Comment: Have you cleared all cache & session data?

Comment: Also enable/check the Magento logs. Blank screen is often a hidden error message.

Comment: thanks guys, I'll take a look tomorrow..

Comment: Tried enabling the Magento logs but nothing is outputting there... Cleared cache and session data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sussed it out hadn't installed properly, within the app/design folder - :-)